# contextBroker only working localy

Tags: json, centos6, fiware-orion

I installed the ContextBroker on my VM with the OS 6.8.5
The services are up and running. When i do a curl on the local maschine 
(logged in with ssh) like this

```
curl localhost:1026/version
```

I got a successfull reply

```
{
  "orion" : {
  "version" : "1.4.1",
  "uptime" : "0 d, 4 h, 27 m, 17 s",
  "git_hash" : "905d5fa58ace7fa4f14330ddc982b41cf9b30be6",
  "compile_time" : "Mon Oct 10 17:15:28 CEST 2016",
  "compiled_by" : "fermin",
  "compiled_in" : "centollo"
}
}
```

Now i tried this with postman from a client maschine
GET `http://10.1.1.101:1026/version` 
and got the following message.

```
{
  "orionError": {
    "code": "400",
    "reasonPhrase": "Bad Request",
    "details": "Orion accepts no payload for GET/DELETE requests. HTTP header Content-Type is thus forbidden"
  }
}
```

Header is defined 
Content-Type        application/json
Accept              application/json

Does anybody know what i am dooing wrong ?
Because the port is running and open.
Could it be the cloud environment?

Cheers
Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the error message seems to be pretty descriptive:

> "details": "Orion accepts no payload for GET/DELETE requests. HTTP header Content-Type is thus forbidden"

Thus probably postman in adding the a Content-Type header for some reason. Once you manage to get postman not adding that header, the problem probably would be disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved the problem.

1st it was a sign in the body, 2nd I cleared the cookies.

It is now working. I leave it online if somebody has the same problem.